# Не срабатывает условие выхода из итератора

Tags: python, ооп, классы

В созданном классе генератора чтения строк из файла не срабатывает условие выхода из итератора. Файл читается повторно.

Создал класс чтения файла построчно, и не могу разобратmся с выходом из итерации. Помогите разобраться. Как лучше поступить в этой ситуации. Нужен вывод по одной строке.

```
class Get_event():

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.line = None

    def __iter__(self):
        self.i = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        with open(file=self.file, mode='r') as f:
            self.line = f.read()
            if self.line == '':
                raise StopIteration
            return self.line


path = 'D:\\events.txt'

events = Get_event(file=path)
for event in events:
    print(event)
```

Comment: Так вы на каждой итерации читаете целиком весь файл. Опишите в вопросе ожидаемое поведение. На одну итерацию должна выводиться одна строка? Тогда и файл нужно открывать не там.

Comment: Спасибо. Нужен вывод по одной строке.

Comment: Нужен -  ну так поставьте соответствующий оператор. Напомню, есть такая функция file.readline() -  вот ее и используйте.

Comment: Файл открывайте в `__init__` и храните сразу открытый файл, а не название файла. А в `__next__` читайте очередную строку через `readline()`.

Comment: И перед `raise StopIteration` ещё закройте файл, кстати, его же нужно в какой-то момент закрыть. А, я не прав, файл нужно в `__iter__` открывать. Иначе вы не сможете более одного раза проитерироваться целиком через цикл `for` по этому объекту. Вам может и не нужно это, но так будет правильнее.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Comment: Если это весь код, то можете файл и вообще не закрывать, конечно. Но хороший стиль - это закрывать файл когда вы больше не собираетесь им пользоваться. Так то он и сам закроется по окончании работы кода. Кстати, `self.line` вам вроде бы вообще не нужен, ну я не знаю, может вы его где-то ещё потом используете. Достаточно локальной переменной `line`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Get_event():
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        
    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.path) as file:
            yield from iter(file.readline, "")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Тогда уже логично через with open, но в целом ок.

Comment: @insolor просто в варианте с `return`, `with` не работал, поэтому забыл

Answer (score 0):

Компиляция советов из комментариев:

1. Использовать `readline` вместо `read`
2. Открывать файл в `__init__`
3. Закрывать файл перед выбрасыванием исключения

```
class Get_event():

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.file = open(file=self.filepath, mode='r')

    def __iter__(self):
        self.i = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.line = self.file.readline()
        if self.line == '':
            self.file.close()
            raise StopIteration
        return self.line


path = 'D:\\events.txt'

events = Get_event(file=path)
for event in events:
    print(event)
```

Comment: Открывать файл лучше в `__iter__`. Иначе если сделать потом ещё один такой же цикл `for` будет ошибка. Мелочь, но всё-таки.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну по логике два раза по одному и тому же итератору и не должно быть возможно пройти. Если нужно второй раз - создаем новый объект Get_event, и по нему идем.

Comment: @insolor Ну я честно говоря до сих пор путаюсь как там чего. Надо будет почитать

Comment: @CrazyElf, тут просто разница между iterable и iterator. Iterator реализует методы `__iter__` и `__next__`, `__iter__` возвращает сам объект-итератор, `__next__` вытаскивает по одному объекту или кидает StopIteration. Обычно итераторы после "исчерпания" нельзя повторно использовать. Если же объект - iterable, то он реализует только метод `__iter__`, который при каждом вызове возвращает новый отдельный объект-итератор (не являющийся исходным объектом), такой iterable объект можно сколько угодно раз передавать в for, например, именно за счет того что каждый раз новый итератор создается.

Comment: @CrazyElf вот в ответе Danis кстати iterable объект, не итератор.

Comment: @insolor Ага, я видел, теперь понял, спасибо

Comment: А try: except: finally: не нужны здесь на случай, если по ходу чтения сработает исключение, чтобы в finally закрыть файл?